# How to port dirent.h usage from gcc to Windows compiler

Tags: c++, windows, portability

I wrote a program that iterates through the directories recursively and looks for a certain filetype, using the "dirent.h" which works perfektly fine (windows/Linux) with the gcc, but unfortunately I now need to compile it just using the windows compiler which doesn't know the "dirent.h", and fails therefore to compile. How do I import the dirent library to the windows compiler and link it staticly to my executable?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use this implementation of the `dirent` API for Windows: [link](http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php).

Comment: well trying that out I got uncounterable unsolveable symbol exceptions